# Wordpress ajax query returns zero

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am doing simple wordpress select query and want to do this with ajax jquery and do not want the page to refresh when I press search button and writing text in search textbox. As soon as I press search button I get zero .. please help in this because if I do it with normal query it gives the results with form submit now it gives zero no matter what I do. Thanks

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {      
    jQuery("#Submityourskill").click(function(e){ 
        event.preventDefault();      
        jQuery.post(yes.ajaxurl,{action : 'doit'},
            function( response) {//start of funciton
                // alert(response);
                //jQuery("#searchtextbox").val(response);
                jQuery("#result").append(response);
                jQuery("#textarea").html(response);
                return false;
            } //end of function
        );
    }); // click button function finishing here
}); //end of main loop
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div><input maxlength="200" name="secretcode" size="200" type="text" value="" placeholder="Type Here !" />
    <input id="Submityourskill" name="Submit" type="submit" value="Search Record" /></div>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>

PHP:

function doit() {
    if(isset($_POST['secretcode'])!= ''){
        if($_POST['Submit']) {
            $secretcode=$_POST['secretcode'];
            global $wpdb;
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_store_locator WHERE sl_description='$secretcode'";
            $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            foreach( $results as $result ) {
                echo $result->sl_description;
            }
            exit();
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_doit', 'doit');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_doit', 'doit' );

function add_myjavascript(){  
    wp_register_script( 'globals', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/js/ajax-implementationn.js", array( 'jquery' ) ); 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'globals' );
    // use wp_localize_script to pass PHP variables into javascript
    wp_localize_script( 'globals', 'yes', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}  
add_action( 'init', 'add_myjavascript' );
```

Thanks everybody ...

Comment: `function(e)` involves then using `e`, not `event`. It should be `e.preventDefault()`. What is `yes`? And what do you mean "I get zero"? Also could you explain "if I do it with normal query it gives the results" ? What is "normal"?

Comment: I have changed event to e .. thanks for that ... I meant to say that if I don't use e.preventDefault() in my jquery page then the search query returns the accurate results but as soon as I add this I get '0' as soon as I write my search criteria and press search button. I hope it make sense ... thanks

Comment: So you mean, if you use `e.preventDefault()`, the ajax response is 0, and if you don't write it, the ajax response is correct? Doesn't make much sense... there's just no relation. There's something I don't get.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by appending the text string response to a div, and then trying to put it into an element with ID 'textarea' that is not shown?

Comment: no please ignore the textarea line in jquery. The div is the actual html tag which is getting the output as appended to it. That's it please ignore the textarea field. I don't know if my function is properly registering and zero get's appended to the div as soon as I press search button.

Comment: Well, since you are returning a text string, you should use jQuery("#result").text(response); Append only appends HTML.